# Limit not evaluating

Tags: maple

I have the following function defined in Maple:

```
restart;
_local(Psi);

Psi := t -> (t^(-alpha) - 1)/alpha
```

I want to find the limit of the function as t tends to zero assuming alpha is greater than 0.

```
(limit(Psi(t), t = 0) assuming (0 < alpha));
```

However I am getting `limit((t^(-alpha) - 1)/alpha, t = 0)` which is not the answer. Also I have tried using `Psi(0)` but I am getting `-1/alpha` which is again incorrect. The answer is supposed to be infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f := (t^(-alpha) - 1)/alpha:

limit(f, t=0, right) assuming alpha>0;

          infinity
```

Comment: Many thanks @acer. Is there any explanation why using a function in terms of Psi failed to produce the answer?

Comment: The problem was not related to function/operator versus expression. Your problem was that the limit from the left is the not as you expected/claimed.